# Trouble adding a custom css file via local.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.2.4

I am attempting to add a custom css file instead of just adding changes to `styles.css`, I would like a separate file where all of my css changes to my theme are kept.

To do this I have created a `custom.css` file and placed it in `skin/frontend/mytheme/default/css`

The file right now contains a Video Wrapper that I am using to make youtube videos on CMS pages responsive.

The video wrapper is called by  on any CMS page with the following

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
<iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/<<video>>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

content of custom.css

```
/* Video Wrapper */
.videoWrapper {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
padding-top: 25px;
height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Then in my local.xml file I have modified it to contain the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name=“head”>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="footer_links">
                <action method="addLink" translate="label title"><label>FAQ</label><url>faq</url><title>Frequently Asked Questions</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>5</position>
                </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

The above did not work, so I tried again with the below, and it still did not work.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customd6css>
        <reference name=“head”>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
    </customd6css>
    <default>
        <reference name="footer_links">
                <action method="addLink" translate="label title"><label>FAQ</label><url>faq</url><title>Frequently Asked Questions</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>5</position>
                </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Any help or advice on where I am screwing this up would be helpful, when I inspect the page source custom.css is not among the resources.  I could of course just give up and place the css changes directly in `styles.css`, but would prefer not to.

I know the problem is with my `local.xml` file, because both of my above attempts caused the `local.xml` to not be processed properly, because with both my FAQ link disappears.

Comment: Check My answer and let me know

Answer (score 1):

change below code from

```
<reference name=“head”>
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet></action>
    </reference>
```

To

```
   <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet></action>
    </reference>
```

and its working "" in reference name has issue